# Is it possible to use alias expansion with shell's builtin commands in Git?

Tags: git, shell, alias

I have the following alias in my `.gitconfig`:

```
freq = !history | cut -c 8- | grep ^git | sort | uniq -c | sort -n -r | head -n 5
```

It should show the 5 git commands I use most. Taken from here: http://alblue.bandlem.com/2011/04/git-tip-of-week-aliases.html (I know the article is old)

When I run the command, it doesn't output anything:

```
$ git freq
$
```

But if I run `history | cut -c 8- | grep ^git | sort | uniq -c | sort -n -r | head -n 5`, output is given:

```
$ history | cut -c 8- | grep ^git | sort | uniq -c | sort -n -r | head -n
   5 git log
   5 git status
   5 git current
   5 git co master
   4 git co other-branch
```

I guess that this is because `history` is a shell builtin command, and if I change the `freq` alias, e.g. to:

```
freq = !history
```

I get:

```
$ git freq
error: cannot run history: No such file or directory
fatal: While expanding alias 'freq': 'history': No such file or directory
$
```

Is there a way to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Cause

After reading the question, I also thought the problem was due to the fact that `history` is a shell builtin.

#### Debugging git

Git commands can be debugged by setting the `GIT_TRACE` environment variable
to `true` (for more info, see the relevant section on [Git Internals - Environment Variables](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables) from Scott Chacon’s Git Book).

```
$ GIT_TRACE=true git freq

10:14:11.901296 git.c:554               trace: exec: 'git-freq'
10:14:11.901296 run-command.c:341       trace: run_command: 'git-freq'
10:14:11.932496 run-command.c:341       trace: run_command: 'history | tail'
10:14:11.963697 run-command.c:192       trace: exec: '/bin/sh' '-c' 'history | tail' 'history | tail'
```

[Checking the source](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/run-command.c#L192) shows that the external command is processed by the `execv_shell_cmd` function which calls `sane_execvp`, a more user friendly front-end to the `execvp` *standard library* function which – if the command name doesn’t contain a slash – searches each directory in the PATH for an executable with the same name as the command. Since `history` is a shell built-in, it won’t ever be found so it returns an error. See

- [execvp man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execvp)
- [How does execvp run a command?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14301670/1640661)
- [execvpe.c](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=posix/execvpe.c;h=588e7a71b1a5b507c7628b4ec7a467f4ba78b1d3;hb=HEAD)

---

Not being one to let things go, I later carried out further experiments using other shell built-ins and those experiments worked  out so I figured it must be something else:

#### No history for non-interactive shells

Reading the Bash manual explains that [Bash History Facilities](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-History-Facilities.html) are only used in [interactive shells](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/What-is-an-Interactive-Shell_003f.html) while shells started by an `exec` call are non-interactive. That’s why running the `history` builtin doesn’t print any output.

---

### Solutions

#### Option 1: Turn on the history features in the non-interactive shell

Thanks to [Gilles on Unix and Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/5701/22812), it turns out that the history features in the non-interactive shell can be turned on by setting the `HISTFILE` shell variable and then running `set -o history` as can be seen by running:

```
bash -c "HISTFILE=~/.bash_history; set -o history; history"
```

Setting the following alias in `.gitconfig` will work:

```
freq = "!HISTFILE=$HOME/.bash_history; set -o history; history | cut -c 8- | grep ^git | sort | uniq -c | sort -n -r | head -n 5"
```

Note: If you’re using a shell other than Bash, you’ll need to specify the name of the file that your shell saves its command history to. If you are using Bash, it’s possible that the `HISTFILE` shell variable is set to something other than `$HOME/.bash_history`.

Also, shell variables such as `HISTFILE` should not be exported as an environment variable (available to git) which is why I didn’t use it here.

#### Option 2: Read from the history file

A simpler solution would be to read directly from the shell history file:

```
freq = !grep ^git $HOME/.bash_history | sort | uniq -c | sort -n -r | head -n 5
```

This would give the same results as running the `history` command in a new interactive shell since when a new shell starts, it has no commands in its history other than what it has read from the history file.

Also, there’s no need for the `cut` command when reading directly from the history file.

#### Option 3: Bash alias

The other option is to forget about using a Git alias and to simply use a Bash alias:

```
alias git-freq='history | cut -c 8- | grep ^git | sort | uniq -c | sort -n -r | head -n
```

---

### Keeping the shell history file up to date

I thought I’d add the following as useful ancillary information. Note that it applies to an interactive Bash shell and it may or may not work for other modern shells.

I often run multiple shells on the same host at the same time and I don’t want saved history commands to be over-written when exiting a shell. Here are my `.bashrc` settings which ensure that the shell history file is written to after every command:

```
# Append history entries on logout - instead of over-writing the history file.
shopt -s histappend

# Don't store duplicate lines in the history.
# Ignore any commands that begin with a space.
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:ignorespace

# Use a very large history file to store lots of commands.
# See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/088
HISTFILESIZE=5000
# Keeping a large history requires system resources
HISTSIZE=3000

# Append to the history file after every command.
PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a"
```

Comment: Reading from `.bash_history` doesn't seem to give the same results as `history` does in my case. When the alias is set to your workaround I don't get any output (I have checked my ~/.bash_history and in fact there's no `git` command). However, if I run `$ history` I can see a few `git` commands I have issued before... So maybe I can use something like `!bash -c "history"`?

Comment: I have tried: `freq = !bash -c "history | cut -c 8- | grep ^git | sort | uniq -c | sort -n -r | head -n 5"` but it doesn't seem to work, too...

Comment: Thank you for your update. `# Don't store duplicate lines in the history.` Does it mean that if I type `git log` once and then retype it again, it will be stored only once inside `.bash_history`?

Comment: @tonix. That's correct. You may or may not want this behaviour.

Comment: And what is the difference between `HISTFILESIZE` and `HISTSIZE`? Does the first mean "maximum size of the file in (bytes? kB?) before older lines will be deleted"? What about `HISTSIZE`?

Comment: There's a great explanation of these settings at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/088

Comment: @tonix I’ve re-edited my answer a few times since yesterday and I’d suggest re-reading it as I discovered the real cause of your problem - and a solution.

Comment: Yeah, I am sorry for the absence, I had some things hanging around I had to do. Thank you for your help, I will go with the `alias` for now!